# How to get number of billable customers per month SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is what my table looks like:

[image: cust db table]

NOTE: Don't worry about the BMI field being empty in some rows. We assume that each row is a reading. I have omitted some columns for privacy reasons.

I want to get a count of the number of active customers per month. A customer is active if they have at least 18 readings in total (1 reading per day for 18 days in a given month). How do I write this SQL query? Assume the table name is 'cust'. I'm using SQL Server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your table doesn't even have an indicator for the customer.  I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie to stackoverflow. patient id = cust id

Comment: Look at your data carefully. Then read your definition of active - both of them and they are not exactly the same. I see two rows for the same customer with the same date. 18 readings within a month (you left that part out) is not the same as 1 reading per day for 18 days (which might also not be precisely the logic you want). So it seems you want customers who have readings on at least 18 different dates within a month? Perhaps a bit pedantic but you also need to test these edge conditions. That requires precision.

Comment: Do the readings need to be on consecutive days?

Comment: Nope, the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably a patient is a customer in your world.  If so, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select yyyy, mm, count(*)
from (select year(createdat) as yyyy, month(createdat) as mm,
             patient_id,
             count(distinct convert(date, createdat)) as num_days
      from t
      group by year(createdat), month(createdat), patient_id
     ) ymp
where num_days >= 18
group by yyyy, mm;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask what is the purpose of the "ymp". I tried on sql server and it didn't run without the ymp. I tried using another random character like "t" instead of the "ymp" and it still ran. What is this for?

Comment: @DivitJawa It is just an alias  I suspect it stands for Year Month Patient.   Sub-queries require an alias

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I've never really come across this for some reason. I haven't dabbled with SQL much, which might be why.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to group by patient and the month, then group again by just the month**

```sql
SELECT
  mth,
  COUNT(*) NumPatients
FROM (
    SELECT
      EOMONTH(c.createdat) mth
    FROM cust c
    GROUP BY EOMONTH(c.createdat), c.patient_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 18
-- for distinct days you could change it to:
--  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(c.createdat AS date)) >= 18
) c
GROUP BY mth;
```